# How to hide cmd.exe console?

Tags: internet-explorer, cmd

I put this below code inside my *.dll for Internet Explorer.

```
FILE  *child = _popen("java -jar c:\\simmetrics.jar c:\\chtml.txt c:\\thtml.txt > c:\\output.txt", "r");

fclose(child);
```

My problem is, when I run my Internet Explorer, the will be a cmd.exe console open too. I don't want the console to suddenly appear when I run my browser. How can I avoid this or hide it or not to execute it at all)?

update:

How to properly call javaw from the code? It still popping up the console windows :(

```
FILE  *child = _popen("javaw -jar c:\\simmetrics.jar c:\\chtml.txt c:\\thtml.txt > c:\\output.txt", "r");
```

update:

Is there any other way? The console window still being called everytime I run this line of code inside my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) instead of `_popen`.  It's a bit more cumbersome, but you can pass the [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863(VS.85).aspx) flag as part of the `dwCreationFlags` parameter to prevent the console window from appearing.

If you need to capture the output of the process you've created, you can use `CreatePipe`/`ReadFile` to do so.  MSDN has a thorough example of doing this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Try using `javaw.exe` instead. It's the same as `java.exe` except it's a Windows graphical program and not a console program so it won't open a command console. (As a side effect you won't be able to see stdout and stderr without redirecting them to a log file.)

Comment: When I type javaw inside my cmd console, and press ENTER, there seems no help-manual appear. May I know why and how to fix this?

Comment: Is there any other way. It still pops up the cmd console.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer pointed out, we can use the CreateProcess function with the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag.  Here is a working example of that.  It has a lot of extra power not shown here.  This is just the minimum you need to replace system() or the _spawn() family.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

// Spawn creates a cmd.exe window.  CreateProcess doesn't.
//if ( _spawnl( _P_WAIT, szFileNameBAT, szFileNameBAT, NULL ) ) {  
if ( !CreateProcess( szFileNameBAT, szFileNameBAT, NULL, NULL, false,
                     CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi  ) ) {
  MyErrorFunc( "CreateProcess( \"%s\" ): %d", szFileNameBAT, GetLastError() );
  goto MyErrorHandling;
}

WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```